# How does Garbage Collector works for Primitive Data type in Java?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

As we know for Object its works through Reference counting and other such Algorithm.
But for Primitive Data types, we can't make it `NULL` like:

```
int a = NULL;
```

How does Garbage Collector work for Primitive datatypes in Java?

Comment: A primitive data type is always contained in either an object or an invocation stack frame.  It's not separately collected.

Comment: Understand that when you have, say, `String someString;` declared, `someString` itself is never separately collected -- it's essentially a "primitive" just like an `int` or a `double`.  Rather, the object that `someString` points to is (eventually) collected.

Comment: Objects are *not* reference counted. They're subject to tracing garbage collection.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [are java primitives garbage collected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746801/are-java-primitives-garbage-collected)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Primitive data types are either fields in objects or used in arrays which themselves are objects. For the garbage collector these fields are not relevant, because they do not contain pointers. They can be perfectly ignored and will be freed together with the object/array once it gets garbage collected.

Answer (score 5):

Primitives go on `stack` and freed immediately when they go out of scope, there is no GC for it. As oppose to objects that go to `heap` and stored in more long term memory.

Comment: Actually, most primitives are in objects.

Comment: Local variables are stored on Stack and they are freed when its out of scope.What about Instance Variables which can be of Primitive type

Comment: Primitive instance variables are part of an object; their memory is freed when the GC collects the object.

Comment: This answer is plain wrong. ints can be inside objects, which go into heap, not stack.