# How many objects are eligible for garbage collector when we create an array of arrays?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

```
public class GarbageCollectionTest{

    public static void main(String...args){
        int [][]a = new int[4][3];//line 1
        a[0] = new int[2];// line 2
        a[2] = new int[3];// line 3
        a = new int[3][2];  //line 4
    }
}
```

I am little bit confuse that how many objects are eligible for garbage collector after line 3. I have searched the solution regarding this but I haven't been satisfied by the answers I've found.

Comment: did you mean after executing line 4 ?

Comment: Well, you reassign two objects, so I assume that you have two objects (two arrays) available for garbage collection.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to understand about garbage collection? Generally speaking the GC just "does the right thing" and cleans up objects you can no longer refer to.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, let's go through it line by line:

You create a new int 2D-Array a:

```
int [][]a = new int[4][3];//line 1
```

You replace two arrays in a:

```
a[0] = new int[2];// line 2
a[2] = new int[3];// line 3
```

You reassign a and create a new array:

```
a = new int[3][2];  //line 4
```

After line 3 the two arrays you replaced in line 2&3 will be picked up.

After line 4 the garbage collector will pick up every object (array) that was placed in the "old" a, so 4 objects (int is **not** an object, see Konstantins answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20428532/how-does-garbage-collector-works-for-primitive-data-type-in-java)).

4 + 2 + the reference to the "old" a itself = 7 in total

*I hope I got it right ;)*

Answer (score 1):

Garbage collection occurs when your program no longer has any references to an object, not when objects are created, so "when we create an array of arrays" nothing happens with respect to garbage collection.

A two-dimensional array of primitives, like an `int[][]`, consists of one object array holding references to *n* `int[]` arrays (where *n* is the size of the outer array - 4 in line 1 of your example). When you assign that two-dimensional array to `a` you create a reference from `a` to the outer array, and in turn to the inner primitive arrays, therefore the garbage collector will not remove any of those objects.

On line two you construct a new `int[]` and then assign it to the first index of the outer array. This assignment (not the creation of the array) causes the `int[]` that was previously assigned to index `0` to become eligible for garbage collection since there is no longer any way to reference it - it's "garbage".

Line three is the same, you construct a new `int[]` then assign it to an index, removing the only reference to the previously referenced array. It too is now eligible for collection. So after line three there are two `int[]` objects that can be collected.

Line four constructs a new `int[][]`, doing the same work as above (one object array holding *n* `int[]` arrays), then assigning that array to `a`, thereby removing the only reference to the previous two-dimensional array. At this point the GC can see that nothing is referencing the old array and cleans it up. Once that happens there are no remaining references for the inner arrays either, and the GC can clean those up too.

After line four you can still reference this new array via `a`, and in turn the arrays it contains. The arrays you'd previously constructed are no longer reachable, and therefore will eventually be cleaned up by the GC. Once the GC has had a chance to run all that will be left in memory is the array referenced by `a` and the inner arrays it in turn refers to.